# Double Conditioned selection of data in r

Tags: r, sum, range, selection

I read extensively about selection with condition using function like **aggregate** or the package **pylr** but seems ok for my case.

I am sure is not difficult to program, but I would like some input. 
Basically how to start, what's the line of reasoning that you would follow.

Thanks for any advice.

So my simplified dataset  looks like this

```
time.stamp <- c(21.0,21.1,21.2,21.3,21.4)
behavior <- c("close", "1", "close","1","close")
event_type <- c("start","point","stop","point","start")

example <- data.frame(time.stamp,behavior,event_type)



  time.stamp behavior event_type
1       21.0    close      start
2       21.1        1      point
3       21.2    close       stop
4       21.3        1      point
5       21.4    close      start
```

My research question is: which is the number of behavior==1 during the behavior==Close.

**For example in this case the answer would be 1**
Because the second 1 is after a Close&Stop.

Among the other possible solution I thought of subsetting by the range of time.stamps that are in between a close&start  and a close&stop but I would not know how to translate this in code.

As I said I would love some input on how to think the problem.

Thanks a lot,
I hope to learn something.
Cheers

Comment: Yes, number/count of cases for which behavior==1 if the previous event_type==start and start of "close", not of other possible type of behavior that I didn't put to keep it simple. Thanks for the effort to understand

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess to solve this, you don't need any special packages. Using only 'base':

`length( which( example$behavior[which( example$behavior == 'close' & as.character(example$event_type) == 'stop')+1] == 1 ) )`

EDIT: After clearing what is required output, code changes to:

```
sum((which( example$behavior == 'close' & as.character(example$event_type) == 'stop') - which( example$behavior == 'close' & as.character(example$event_type) == 'start')) - 1)
```

Best,
Adii_

Comment: Thanks. The problem with your suggestion is that often I have more than one 1 (sorry for the pun). Would you suggest to introduce a for loop to solve this?

Comment: I'm not rly sure what you mean about more than on 1?

Comment: try your code with the following new dataset and you will understand `time.stamp <- c(21.0,21.1,21.11,21.12,21.2,21.3,21.4,21.5)
behavior <- c("close", "1","1","1", "close","1","close","close")
event_type <- c("start","point","point","point","stop","point","start","stop")

example <- data.frame(time.stamp,behavior,event_type)`

Comment: I'm still confused. In new data set only row 6 is following your conditions, so count == 1. This is what my code returns. What do I understand bad?

Comment: Your code returns 1 but the right answer is 3, because there are only three 1s that are in between behavior=close & event_type=start and behavior=close & event_type=stop

Comment: If always sequence is: close-start is first, 1's after, and close-stop ending sequence, this code will work:
`sum((which( example$behavior == 'close' & as.character(example$event_type) == 'stop') - which( example$behavior == 'close' & as.character(example$event_type) == 'start')) - 1)`

Comment: It seems to work really nicely. I like the simple reasoning, I will try to learn from this...

Answer (score 0):

I would do in this way:

```
n = nrow(example)
length(which(example$behavior[2:n]==1 & example$event_type[1:n-1]!= "stop"))
```

Comment: Actually it works only in this specific case because the number of rows are 1s are not always `[1:n-1]!= "stop"`. But thanks anyhow is a starting point