# Triple Conditioned selection of data in r

Tags: r, selection, conditional-statements

I am expanding a question asked 5 months ago:
[Double Conditioned selection of data in r](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25868401/double-conditioned-selection-of-data-in-r)

I need to add a condition now and I cannot do it on the suggested solution.
Apparentely my coding skill have not improved much :/

reproducible example:

```
time.stamp <- c(1:22)
behavior <- c("close", "1","2","1","1", "close","1","1","close","close","distance","1","distance","close", "1","right","2","1","2","right","1", "close")
event_type <- c("start","point","point","point","point","stop","point","point","start","stop", "start","point","stop","start","point","start","point","point","point","stop","point","stop")


example <- data.frame(time.stamp,behavior,event_type)
```

I would like to sum the number of example$behavior=="1" during each interval of the example$behavior=="close". The intervals are defined by the column example$event_type by "start" and "stop".

The suggested solution was:

```
sum((which( example$behavior == 'close' & as.character(example$event_type) == 'stop') - which( example$behavior == 'close' & as.character(example$event_type) == 'start')) - 1)
```

However with this approach I count any event in between my start (`example$event_type == 'start'`) and end (`example$event_type == 'stop'`), also the example$behavior named "2", and the one named "right", beside what I really want: example$behavior== "1"

Basically I would like to be able to select what I count but I did not find a way.
The output is 11, the corrected one would be 6!

Here what I tried:

```
sum(which( example$behavior[(which( example$behavior == 'close' & as.character(example$event_type) == 'stop') - which( example$behavior == 'close' & as.character(example$event_type) == 'start')) - 1]== "1"))
```

or:

```
count<-0
for(i in 1:length(example$behavior)){
    if(example$behavior[i]=="close"){
        while (i>= example$event_type%in% "start" && i<=example$event_type%in% "stop"){
            count=count+1   
        }   
    }
}
```

Any suggestion? It would love to be able to create a function in which I can change the various parameters and be flexible.

Any comment on the reasoning I should have are much appreciated.
Thanks for any input.

have fun

Comment: Could you elaborate why the correct output would be 6? Your question isn't very clear...

Comment: Sure, and sorry for this, only the rows "2","4","5","15","18","21" have a "example$behavior==1" that is in between example$behavior == 'close' & example$event_type == 'start' and example$behavior == 'close' & example$event_type == 'stop'. Better?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I post a solution.

The trick for this kind of problem is to **find an unique identifier**, in my case merging the columns `example$behavior` and `example$event_type` will provide unique cases, the rest is matter of subsetting and looping.
The reproducible example is given in the question.

```
example$beh_eve <- paste(example$behavior,"_",example$event_type,sep="")
start<-which( example$beh_eve == 'close_start')
end<-which( example$beh_eve == 'close_stop') 

sum_1<-0
for(i in 1:length(start)){
    xx <-example[start[i]:end[i],]
    s<-sum(xx$behavior=="1",na.rm=TRUE)
    sum_1<-sum_1+s
}
print(sum_1)
```

Now I will try to write a function in order to generalize.
Any suggestions to improve or speed up the answer are welcome.

Have fun